# Why is the searchview crashing and closing on typing in it

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview, string.xml

- What are the correct lines of code for extracting string.xml data and
  creating a search view on a recycler view?

### Main Activity Code:

```
    package com.example.search_view;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        ArrayList<SearchModel> searchModels = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
        private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.r1);
            setSearchModels();
            RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, searchModels);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
    
              private void setSearchModels() {
            String [] itemNames = 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_items);
            for (int i=0;i<itemNames.length;i++) {
                searchModels.add(new SearchModel(itemNames[i]));
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
            MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.s1);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String  newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    
    
                    return false;
                }
            });
    
    
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }
    }
```

### Adapter Class:

```
    package com.example.search_view;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Filter;
    import android.widget.Filterable;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import org.w3c.dom.Text;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    
        Context context;
        ArrayList<SearchModel> searchModels;
        ArrayList<SearchModel> backup;
    
        public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, 
            ArrayList<SearchModel>searchModels) {
            this.context = context;this.searchModels = searchModels;
            this.backup=new ArrayList<>(searchModels);
    
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
    
    
            return new RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.t1.setText(searchModels.get(position).getItemNames());
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return searchModels.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return filter;
        }
    
    
        Filter filter=new Filter() {
    
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                ArrayList<SearchModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if(charSequence.toString().isEmpty()){
                    filteredList.addAll(backup);
                }else {
                    for(SearchModel obj : backup){
                        if(obj.getItemNames().toString().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()))
                          filteredList.add(obj);
                        }
                    }
    
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values=filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                searchModels.clear();
                searchModels.addAll((Collection<? extends SearchModel>) filterResults.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
    
    
            }
        };
    
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView t1;
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                t1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            }
        }
    }
```

- I want someone to assist me regarding taking items from string.xml
  and creating a search view on an already framed recycler view as my
  app is closing and crashing as I type in the search view.

Comment: Can you share your stack trace of when the app crashes? It will possibly have the line at which the app crashes. It will help in identifying potential sources of error.

Comment: Replace `RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, searchModels);` with `adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, searchModels);`

Comment: It did not help Sir, please help